# Comparing dates in PHP paradox

Tags: php, date

I have the weirdest issue ever:

Trying to compare today's date with a date from `$_POST`. I treat the parameters as follows:

```
$str1 = date("d-m-Y");
$str2 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['dateto']));
```

I compare the dates:

```
if ($str2 >= $str1) {
// doing what it is supposed to
}
else {
echo "error";
}
```

Now since this results in an "error", and I am a 100% sure I input a date that is later than today's one, I `echo`-ed the parameters it compares before the logical `if` and the result is:
**02-11-2016** for `$str2` and **27-10-2016** for `$str1`. It is obvous that today is in October and the input date is in November, but it still runs the logical operator as ***false***.

Any opinions?

Comment: Because you're doing a string comparison. `0` is before `2`. Use DateTime objects and compare.

Comment: Jon Stirling gave you already the correct answer. Another is, when you change the format from `"d-m-Y" ` to `"Y-m-d" ` then even the string comparison would work.

Comment: `if( strtotime($_POST['dateto']) >= time() )`

Comment: Yet another solution would be to compare `mktime(0,0,0)` and `strtotime($_POST['dateto'])`.

Comment: Well I compare dates the same way in 2 other pages but the input date I take from SQL and everything seems to be working completely fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, use **[createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)**

```
$format = "d-m-Y";
$date1  = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, date('d-m-y'));
$date2  = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST['dateto']);    
if($date1 >= $date2){
// doing what it is supposed to
}
else {
echo "error";
}
```

Comment: What line can I use to transform a datetime (meaning "Y-m-d" format) from SQL to the same type of object as $date1 but in "d-m-Y" format? I tried this: `$date3 = $row['date3']; $date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $date3);` but when I var_dump($date3) it says just "bool(false)"

Comment: I did it! Turns out I should first apply date() with the correct format to $date3 before applying datetime::createfromformat.

Comment: And how about that: `$datetoday = date("Y-m-d"); $sql="SELECT * FROM offers WHERE usr_id='$of_usr_id' AND date_to>='$datetoday'";` this will always work without problems right? When used like that but in a SQL query?

Comment: @Frank Helligberger :  its also work. if not then try this, 'SELECT * FROM offers WHERE usr_id='$of_usr_id' AND DATE_FORMAT(date_to, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') >= '$datetoday';'

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings, and they are not the same...

I leave you here an example of use:

```
$todays_Date= strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:00",time()));
$input_Date= strtotime("19-11-2008 21:00:00");
if($todays_Date> $input_Date){
    echo "Input date is from the past";
}else{
    echo "Input date is from the future";
}
```

Comment: Why not just `$todays_Date = time()`? Or `strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:00"));`? `date()` automatically assumes the current timestamp, if none is passed.

Comment: @Jota Ge I have another page where instead of an input date I use a date from SQL stored as datetime (meaning it is in "Y-m-d" format). The dates I compare are in "d-m-Y", so how can I transform the date from the SQL to the correct format while using the strtotime() as you adviced me?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `strtotime()`:

```
if( strtotime($_POST['dateto']) >= strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) )
{
    // Do what you're supposed to here.
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: Will this compare not only the dates but the hours too?

Comment: Does it mean that the outcome of date("Y-m-d") is not in a datetime format but in a string?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$str1 = date("d-m-Y");
$str2 = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST['dateto']));
```

try

```
$str1 = time();
$str2 = strtotime($_POST['dateto']);
```

Now you have to unix timestamps to compare. These will give you the results you expect.

Using `>=` on a string where the day is the first part of the string will cause unexpected results as `01-01-2016` is less than `20-07-2015` even though, when comparing on a calendar `01-01-2016` is after ('greater than') than `20-07-2015`.

Another option is to change `date("d-m-Y")` to `date("Ymd")` which will mean the dates can be evaluated using `>=`. Although timestamps seem the simpler option in your case.

Comment: If I try this: `$datetoday = date("Y-m-d"); $sql="SELECT * FROM offers WHERE usr_id='$of_usr_id' AND date_to>='$datetoday'";` this will always work without problems right?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date to time and then compare:

```
$str1 = time();
$str2 = strtotime($_POST['dateto']));

if ($str2 >= $str1) {
// doing what it is supposed to
}
else {
echo "error";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now if I try this: `$datetoday = date("Y-m-d"); $sql="SELECT * FROM offers WHERE usr_id='$of_usr_id' AND date_to>='$datetoday'";` this will always work without problems right?